# Al seleccionar la fecha máxima se están ignorando los segundos

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Utilizando la misma sentencia SQL de siempre para obtener de manera agrupada por códigos la máxima fecha, cuando se encuentra una fecha con la misma hora y minutos, ignora los segundos y la cuenta como si fuera igual.

Este es un ejemplo donde no puedo hacer un max(date).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto también la sentencia SQL de la consulta.

```sql
    SELECT till.code,art.description
      FROM [TCPOS4].[dbo].[transactions] as tra,
           TCPOS4.dbo.articles as art,
           [TCPOS4].[dbo].[trans_articles] as tro,
           [TCPOS4].[dbo].[tills] as till,
           [TCPOS4].[dbo].[shops] as shop

     where tra.till_id=till.id
       and shop.id=till.shop_id 
       and tro.transaction_id=tra.id 
       and art.id=tro.article_id 
       and tra.trans_date =( select max(trans_date) 
                               from tcpos4.dbo.transactions as t2 
                              where t2.till_id=tra.till_id 
                                and trans_date  > '2016-10-26 00:00:00.000' 
                                and trans_date< '2016-10-27 00:00:00.000' 
                           )
     group by till.code, art.description
```

Esta consulta funciona correctamente con todos los registros menos cuando tiene la misma hora con diferentes segundos.

¿Alguna manera de hacer que el max(date) tenga en cuenta los segundos?

Comment: Falta un poco de claridad. Puedes definir mas precisamente lo que sucede cuando "funciona" y "no funciona"? ¿Estas diciendo que con tus 2 registros que tienes como ejemplo, donde la fecha es "casi" igual (aparte de los segundos), que tu consulta devuelve ambos registros como teniendo la "maxima fecha"? Me parece muy raro si es así. Solo debería devolver uno.

Comment: Cuidado con expresiones como *ignora los segundos y la cuenta como si fuera igual.* o *Esta consulta funciona correctamente*. Se prestan a interpretacion. Mas bien, procura ser mas explícito en cuanto a lo que sucede en estos casos. Por ejemplo: *En este caso, la consulta me devueve ambos registros*, etc.

Comment: Me explico. Esta consulta me devuelve siempre los valores que yo deseo, solo cuando me encuentro con una fila que tiene la misma hora y minuto es cuando encuentro el error. Eso pasa porque cuando hago el max(date) parece ser que no tiene en cuenta los segundos, entonces la consulta ve que existen dos fechas iguales y no termina de realizarlo bien. La consulta termina sin devolver nada, ni un registro ni el otro.

Comment: Sospecho que estas asumiendo incorrectamente la causa del problema. Si por alguna razon los segundos fueran ignorados, recibirias ambos registros. No ninguno. El problema debe estar en un lugar diferente. Si deseas mas ayuda, debes compartir suficientes datos para que podamos reproducir el problema.

Comment: Idealmente, usa lo siguiente para crear un ejemplo que reproduce tu problema: http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler, y luego puedes plasmar un enlace en tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> cuando se encuentra una fecha con la misma hora y minutos, ignora los segundos y la cuenta como si fuera igual.

Esta conclusión no tiene ninguna base. Es más, tomando tu propio ejemplo de los 2 registros... si fuera el caso que `max(trans_date)` ignora los segundos, entonces la consulta devolvería ***ambos*** registros. Pero según lo que has comentado, la consulta no devuelve ***ninguno*** de los 2 registros.

Para probar que SQL Server no ignora los segundos, considera el script simplificado siguiente que puedes verificar por tu cuenta:

```sql
create table tbl (
    code int not null,
    description varchar(50) not null,
    trans_date datetime not null
);
go

insert into tbl (code, description, trans_date)
values
(5446, 'TABLETA CHOCOLECHE-CONGUITOS', '2016-10-26 21:10:24'),
(5446, 'BISOLAN LIMON AGUA', '2016-10-26 21:10:04');
go

select * from tbl;
go

select *
  from tbl
 where trans_date = (
     select max(trans_date)
       from tbl
     );
go
```

Resultado:

```
code  description                   trans_date
----  -----------                   ----------
5446  TABLETA CHOCOLECHE-CONGUITOS  26.10.2016 21:10:24
5446  BISOLAN LIMON AGUA            26.10.2016 21:10:04

code  description                   trans_date
----  -----------                   ----------
5446  TABLETA CHOCOLECHE-CONGUITOS  26.10.2016 21:10:24
```

Enlace para ver una demostración: http://rextester.com/HVK22622

Como podrás apreciar, la consulta funciona perfectamente, sin algún problema con los segundos.

De modo que, ¿cuál es la causa real de tu problema? **Hasta que no incluyas [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), no es posible determinarlo.**

Pero lo que sí puedo afirmar es que el problema **no** es causado porque SQL Server ignora los segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es obtener el registro con la fecha máxima a partir de la columna `trans_date` y tome en cuenta los segundos, entonces esto tal vez te sirva:

```
SELECT TOP(1) trans_date FROM tcpos4.dbo.transactions as t2 ORDER BY trans_date DESC
```

Comment: ¿Estás diciendo que `max(trans_date)` no toma en cuenta los segundos, pero `top (1) trans_date` sí?

Comment: No estoy diciendo eso, sólo menciono que con `top (1) trans_date` a mi me ha funcionado y toma en cuenta además las horas, minutos y segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de enmascararla en ma consulta con la siguiente mascara

TO_DATE(:3, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') con el nombre del campo.... de esta forma cuando pongas que te traiga el maximo o el descendente deberia traerte la fecha que buscas